# magento2 how to use extension attributes for totals item

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to set new attribute for totals items to display it below product name on checkout products summary. I want to use "extension attributes" solution to resolve this issue. I'm trying to do it similary to cart attributes, what is described here http://zynovo.com/magento-2-extension-attributes/ but for me it doesn't work. Below is my code

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\TotalsItemInterface">
        <attribute code="producer" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Like is described in tutorial from above link it should generate new version of `TotalsItemInterface` to **var/generation** directory, but but that doesn't happen. I have developer mode and i've tried clear this directory, but it didn't help. How to use properly extension attributes for totals items?